# Identity server 4 + asp.net core: logout on multiple tabs of browser

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

Currently, I am using ID4, asp.net core and angular 2. Everything works well but I am facing one issue, when we open many tabs on browser. Then, we logout on one tab but other tabs still keep token and call API successfully. Can we force or validate token and return to login page on all tabs?

My code to sign out on server

```
    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();

    HttpContext.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());

    var logout = await _interaction.GetLogoutContextAsync(model.LogoutId);

    return Redirect(logout?.PostLogoutRedirectUri);
```

Thanks,

Comment: please share your sign out code (at least server side)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot revoke JWTs: once issued they are valid until they expire. So if you are using Identity Server to issue JWT access tokens then you what you ask isn't possible, so long as *something* has the JWT (and it hasn't expired) then it can be used to gain access to your resources.

Instead you could change to using `Reference Tokens`, which aren't self-contained and upon each use will cause the receiving resource (such as your API) to verify it with the IdSvr. One of the effects of this is that you can then revoke your access tokens, which means it doesn't matter if other tabs think they have the access token because when they try and use it the IdSvr will know that they are no longer valid. If you go down this route you will now need to persist your access tokens, and each protected call to your client will involve it doing a back-channel communication to your IdSvr.